# BCP for sybase using .net

Tags: c#, sybase, bcp

It is possible to run bcp utility for sybase database from .net code?

I want to insert around 10000 rows in database which i have read from file. So rather then doing normal insert which takes much time i want to convert the data in file to bcp readable format.

After doing that how i can call bcp command of sybase database using .net front end?

I am using window application.

Thanks,
Denish

Thanks,
denish

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can run the bcp utility using [Process.Start()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.start.aspx)

Here's an [example](http://www.dotnetperls.com/process-start).